# Failed to invoke PACT method

Tags: java, pact

I have this snippet of code, while trying to create a pact file for my service, but it keeps throwing Failed to invoke pact Method. However, when I run the normal client request, it returns a json object, but when trying to run the pact test, it fails. Below is the snippet of the Test class

```
public class WhatPrimesTest {
    @Rule
    public PactProviderRuleMk2 provider = new PactProviderRuleMk2("PrimeService", "localhost", 81, this);

    @Pact(provider = "PrimeService", consumer = "PrimeServiceClient")
    public RequestResponsePact createPact(PactDslWithProvider builder) {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");


        DslPart etaResults = new PactDslJsonBody()
                .stringType("requestedGtin", "4211")
                .integerType("nodeId", 6132)
                .eachLike("gtinList")
                .eachArrayLike("AVAILABLE", 4322)
                .asBody();

        return builder
                .given("There is a prime gtin 4211 from node 6132")
                .uponReceiving("A request for gtinList")
                .path("/primeService/6132?upc=4211")
                .method("GET")
                .willRespondWith()
                .status(200)
                .headers(headers)
                .body(etaResults).toPact();

    }

    @Test
    @PactVerification("PrimeService")
    public void doTest() {
        System.setProperty("pact.rootDir", "../pacts");  // Change output dir for generated pact-files
        String gtinExpected = "00000000012348";
        String gtinList = new WhatPrime(provider.getPort()).checkEta(6132, "4211");
        System.out.println("According to test eta=" + gtinList);
        //assertTrue(gtinList.);
        //assertArrayEquals("00000000012348", gtinExpected);
    }

}
```

And I get this error when I try to run this test code.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke pact method

    at au.com.dius.pact.consumer.BaseProviderRule.getPacts(BaseProviderRule.java:188)
    at au.com.dius.pact.consumer.BaseProviderRule$1.evaluate(BaseProviderRule.java:63)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at au.com.dius.pact.consumer.BaseProviderRule.getPacts(BaseProviderRule.java:186)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: au.com.dius.pact.model.matchingrules.Category.addRule(Ljava/lang/String;Lau/com/dius/pact/model/matchingrules/MatchingRule;)V
    at au.com.dius.pact.consumer.dsl.PactDslJsonBody.stringType(PactDslJsonBody.java:155)
    at se.ff.bsc.WhatPrimesTest.createPact(WhatPrimesTest.java:33)
    ... 21 more
```

When my service is called, this is what I get as the return.

> [ { requestedGtin: "12348", nodeId: 124, gtinList: [ "00000000012348"
>   ], primeOnHandQuantity: { AVAILABLE: 0, CLAIMS: 0 } } ]

Do you think there is something I'm doing wrong, I need help and would appreciate whatever you can comment on. Thanks

When I remove this block of code

```
DslPart etaResults = new PactDslJsonBody()
                .stringType("requestedGtin", "4211")
                .integerType("nodeId", 6132)
                .eachLike("gtinList")
                .eachArrayLike("AVAILABLE", 4322)
                .asBody();
```

and directly parse the expected body in the .body() function, I get this error message

```
java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address

    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl.<init>(ServerImpl.java:100)
    at sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerImpl.<init>(HttpServerImpl.java:50)
    at sun.net.httpserver.DefaultHttpServerProvider.createHttpServer(DefaultHttpServerProvider.java:35)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.create(HttpServer.java:130)
    at au.com.dius.pact.consumer.MockHttpServer.<init>(MockHttpServer.kt:206)
    at au.com.dius.pact.consumer.MockHttpServerKt.mockServer(MockHttpServer.kt:34)
    at au.com.dius.pact.consumer.ConsumerPactRunnerKt.runConsumerTest(ConsumerPactRunner.kt:12)
    at au.com.dius.pact.consumer.BaseProviderRule.runPactTest(BaseProviderRule.java:148)
    at au.com.dius.pact.consumer.BaseProviderRule.access$100(BaseProviderRule.java:21)
    at au.com.dius.pact.consumer.BaseProviderRule$1.evaluate(BaseProviderRule.java:76)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: A `NoSuchMethodError` is always caused by using a different classpath at execution than the one at compilation. You'd better check the dependencies you are using in each case.

Comment: As @LittleSanti said, please look at the current version you're using.  All our libraries goes through fairly extensive tests before being deployed, so I'd be surprised that we would have missed something so blatant. Maybe try deleting your target directory and reinstalling dependencies and make sure your classpath isn't pointing to a global version of pact-jvm.

Comment: Yeah, that may look like it, but if you look at the error, it always go back to the DSL body. If I pass the body as a whole, I get my test to pass, but that isn't a good solution, as I'd like to try using the normal DSL body. Passing the json body may work for a single array json but not for multi array json. I've tried both. Now, it passes if I comment that line of DSL and pass the body, but when I want to use the DSL, it throws that error you see in the first error BLOCK. And when trying to follow the error log, it goes straight to the DSL block of code

Comment: @J_A_X, that's why we have the post.

Comment: @BiggBen Okay, I'm having some problems understanding what you're saying.  Is it at all possible that you can create an example project of this particular issue on github and share the link?  I'll see if I can replicate locally. Thanks.

Comment: @J_A_X, Sure, I'll do that. I guess what I'm trying to say is that the PACTDSLBODY keeps throwing the "Failed to invoke Pact method" error. Because when I replace that with an actual static JSON body, my contract runs, but when I want to use the PactJsonDSL to form a body for my client mock test, I get that error.

Comment: @BiggBen as Little Santi mentioned, if you have different binaries being used in your path, it could be that the DSL is calling a function that had changed internally in a new release, hence the error.  It doesn't matter if it works with JSON or not, this has to do with getting your dependencies right.